# Internet Explorer 7 float

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

The site listed below works fine in all browsers except IE 7, where the footer moves up against the breadcrumb region, underneath the main content, instead of sitting at the bottom of the page.

Ive tried all the IE tricks I can think of, but I cant move it.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[piarn.org.au](http://piarn.org.au)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `overflow:hidden` on your main wrapper div. This creates a self-clearing div, which may help. Also, it seems that your `.clearfix` class doesn't have any CSS rules affecting it, could you have a typo in your selector? One more thing you may want to try is removing `position: relative` from your main wrapper- it didn't seem to cause any problems when I removed it.

These are all just suggestions, since I am currently on a Mac and can't view your site in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting  just before you are closing your main container with your content - The css for

```
.reset{  clear: both; display: block; font-size: 1px; height: 1px; line-height: 1px;  margin: 0 0 -1px 0; }
```

Comment: True, but i've just experienced that sometimes clear:both isnøt enough :S